# Spaghetti plot in nested data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a spaghetti plot of scores mean values over study waves, this is trivial in simpler data, but this time my data is nested and I am having a hard time conceptualizing the process to plot it.

I generated simulated data with similar characteristics of what I am working with (at the end, since it is long and there is no way of collapsing code blocks here). Data is nested in families (fam) and in zygosity (zyg), what I want is that each observation have their own line across timepoints (wave). Simulated data at the end of the question.

**edit:** I only care about the first MZ of each family, I wil be probably modifying the code to get the plot for DZs.

Now to the MWE ggplot code:

```r
mwe %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(fam) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = wave, y = scores, color = zyg, group = ID)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(w=.2), alpha=.1) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal()
```

- What am I doing wrong here?

```r
mwe <- structure(list(zyg = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("DZ", "MZ"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), wave = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), levels = c("baseline_year_1_arm_1", 
"1_year_follow_up_y_arm_1", "2_year_follow_up_y_arm_1", "3_year_follow_up_y_arm_1", 
"4_year_follow_up_y_arm_1"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
    scores = c(5.52, 3.28, 1.84, -1.45, 0.47, 2.94, 6.51, 0.36, 
    NA, 3.31, 2.73, 1.42, NA, 4.8, 2.97, 2.09, -0.69, 4.22, NA, 
    NA, -6.76, 7.63, 0.3, 2.12, 1.65, NA, -0.97, -0.94, -3.39, 
    -0.52, 2.92, 1.93, 1.26, 1.75, 3.8, 7.72, 4.3, 3.21, 1.95, 
    1.94, -2.07, 0.32, 7.18, 0.61, 4.17, 6.28, 1.02, 2.69, -0.63, 
    5.87, 7.65, 3.23, 0.62, NA, -3.46, -0.43, 1.7, 4.57, 2.58, 
    -2.09, 0.86, 5.93, -0.36, 0.4, 3.48, 0.38, 1.91, NA, 1.68, 
    -2.51, 1.65, 0.27, -1.07, -0.64, 2.31, 5.5, 1.75, -3.89, 
    -2.31, NA, 6.39, 2.25, 0.57, 0.46, 0.24, 0.27, 7.46, 3.96, 
    NA, 5.16, 3.25, 1.53, -0.48, -3.53, 2.17, 4.33, -2.9, 1.5, 
    0.26, 2.1, 1.14, -1.38, -0.02, 2.72, 5.53, 1.12, 0.57, 2.03, 
    -3.6, 3.04, 1.81, 3.63, 3.1, 2.59, 6.85, 2.43, -0.52, -0.84, 
    4.12, -0.12, 0.05, -2.76, 2.87, 1.2, 1.29, -2.98, -2.92, 
    1.38, 1.51, 3.76, -0.03, 0.22, 6.79, 6.67, 1.89, 0.07, NA, 
    3.95, 1.2, 2.02, 1.32, NA, 3.36, -0.03, 1.85, 3.49, 0.18, 
    NA, -0.31, -2.47, 3.9, 6.27, -0.73, 1.52, 2.32, -2.69, 4.08, 
    4.04, 2.53, -0.24, 2.07, 1.86, 4.7, -1.68, 1.53, -2.36, 4.22, 
    -0.38, 5.83, -0.21, NA, 3.69, 3.73, 1.58, 3.71, -0.61, 3.17, 
    5.87, 0.19, -0.34, 4.02, 6, 3.5, 3.83, 1.44, -0.17, NA, 1.01, 
    3.12, 1.34, 1.05, 3.18, 0.7, 0.31, 3.52, 5.09, -0.17, 1.7, 
    2.19, 2.05, 5.18, 1.74, 1.46, 2.54, 4.18, -3.26, -1.4, -0.64, 
    0.3, -1.01, -0.23, 5.26, -1.28, 2.25, 2.67, 0.09, 3.51, -0.05, 
    -0.24, 1.44, 4.22, 3.16, 1.82, 7.04, 3.34, -0.45, 3.6, -1.08, 
    1.47, 2.9, 4.54, 0.07, 1.33, -0.07, -1.25, 5.63, 5.24, NA, 
    1.37, -3.39, 0.99, 2.18, 3.65, 7.17, 3.16, 4.11, NA, 2.32, 
    1.97, 2.4, 2.1, 4.02, -0.57, NA, 5.17, -1.13, 3.59, 1.44, 
    0.84, 2.41, 5.06, 0.51, 0.01, 1.12, 0.99, NA, 5.04, 2.47, 
    0.67, 6.16, 4.88, 0.62, 2.69, 1.09, 3.15, 1.68, 4.71, 4.25, 
    2.13, 2.98, 0.19, -2.9, 2.55, 0.8, 2.72, -1.28, 0.47, -0.52, 
    2.58, -1.11, 2.27, -1.37, -1.64, 1.56, 5.78, 0.43, 1.77, 
    1.54, -0.37, 3.22, 0.2, -1.59, 4, 1.47, 0.55, NA, 2.49, 5.97, 
    NA, -0.15, 1.04, -2.13, 3.87, 4.17, -0.38, 6.55, 0.05, 2.99, 
    6.96, 1.47, 1.36, 1.9, 3.28, 4.7, 1.85, -4.68, 2.23, 2.09, 
    4.73, -0.35, NA, 0.33, -0.76, NA, 5.07, 1.98, 3.42, 0.76, 
    6.89, 3.71, NA, -1.13, 3.66, -1.04, 1.78, -0.09, -0.33, 0.4, 
    -0.16, 2.66, 4.08, -1.17, 1.92, 1.03, 5.03, 1.58, 1.79, 3.1, 
    4.06, 0.09, 6.32, -0.63, 4.22, 1.79, 0.32, NA, 0.45, 1.2, 
    2.48, 0.71, 4.05, 2.65, 5.93, 4.64, NA, 1.59, 5.65, 4.33, 
    -2.02, 1.98, 3.44, 0.98, 3.89, 2.78, 6.1, 2.93, 0.48, 2.06, 
    1.33, -1.78, 5.18, 3.53, 0.19, 3.29, -0.06, 2.88, -1.45, 
    3.81, -1.97, 1.04), age = c(9.65, 9.09, 10.63, 9.63, 9.02, 
    8.98, 10.27, 10.54, 11.37, 8.41, 10.92, 9.3, 11.25, 9.35, 
    10.52, 9.16, 10.52, 10.42, 11.16, 10.77, 10.35, 10.83, 9.66, 
    10.82, 10.79, 10.18, 10.18, 9.17, 9.31, 10.14, 9.93, 8.84, 
    8.43, 10.14, 10.16, 10.17, 9.12, 9.55, 9.58, 10.99, 10.17, 
    11.43, 9.56, 9.88, 10.01, 10.5, 9.28, 10.72, 9.84, 10.19, 
    10.56, 9.11, 10.69, 8.44, 10.64, 9.96, 10.25, 10.11, 9.63, 
    9.22, 9.46, 9.19, 9.62, 11.42, 10.6, 9.54, 8.7, 10.7, 8.8, 
    9.95, 10.2, 9.33, 10.49, 9.97, 10.51, 10.32, 10.06, 8.69, 
    11.6, 9.94, 9.1, 9.95, 9.88, 9.84, 10.92, 10.29, 10.41, 9.74, 
    10.98, 10.06, 11.82, 9.76, 9.24, 9.93, 9.47, 10.3, 9.73, 
    9.78, 10.18, 10.83, 10.8, 9.3, 11.15, 9.98, 10.3, 8.71, 10.43, 
    9.34, 10.67, 10.07, 11.37, 10.27, 10.24, 8.96, 9.58, 9.71, 
    9.74, 9.39, 9.03, 9.72, 10.08, 9.91, 10.44, 10.15, 9.7, 10.39, 
    9.35, 9.66, 10.54, 8.89, 10.57, 9.98, 9.99, 9.71, 10.47, 
    9.8, 10.57, 11.12, 11.78, 9.53, 9.93, 9.54, 10.14, 9.94, 
    9.24, 9.6, 10.91, 8.91, 11.16, 9.76, 10.22, 10.44, 10.14, 
    9.17, 9.8, 9.59, 10.53, 9.61, 11.36, 9.29, 9.81, 9.39, 10.78, 
    10.34, 11.53, 10.34, 10.53, 10.53, 9.62, 10.15, 10.42, 10.09, 
    10.49, 9.75, 10.27, 10.29, 10.36, 10.06, 10.06, 10.63, 10.25, 
    9.49, 10.41, 10.01, 10.06, 8.71, 10.46, 10.12, 9.85, 10.42, 
    9.66, 10.55, 8.73, 10.02, 10.21, 10.16, 9.78, 9.61, 10.07, 
    10.39, 10.28, 9.59, 10.54, 10.55, 10.13, 10.37, 10.83, 10.32, 
    9.69, 9.37, 8.63, 10.29, 11.22, 10.07, 9.35, 9.89, 10.96, 
    10.52, 10.37, 10.54, 9.55, 9.99, 9.82, 9.64, 9.91, 10.26, 
    10.38, 9.68, 9.43, 9.17, 9.66, 10.08, 10.27, 10.39, 9.92, 
    8.58, 8.72, 10.42, 8.92, 9.27, 10.72, 10.58, 9.23, 10.12, 
    10.1, 10, 10.16, 10.48, 9.24, 10.51, 10.15, 10.56, 10.38, 
    9.4, 9, 9.75, 10.22, 9.99, 9.72, 10.02, 10.95, 9.09, 10.96, 
    9.54, 9.38, 10.79, 10.35, 8.53, 10.24, 8.8, 10.66, 9.86, 
    9.9, 10.44, 10.58, 10.28, 9.91, 11.45, 10.19, 10.63, 9.56, 
    9.95, 9.17, 11.16, 10.21, 9.97, 10.43, 9.78, 9.8, 10.1, 8.81, 
    10.68, 9.67, 9.75, 8.97, 10.56, 10.46, 10.96, 9.57, 10.25, 
    10.09, 9.82, 10.18, 10.22, 10.11, 10.75, 9.9, 9.62, 9.88, 
    10.99, 10.83, 10.59, 11.05, 10.25, 9.43, 10.67, 9.66, 9.16, 
    10.15, 9.36, 9.5, 9.07, 10.32, 9.95, 9.7, 10.74, 10.28, 9.87, 
    9.66, 11.06, 9.28, 9.9, 10.74, 10.8, 10.18, 9.97, 9.76, 12.1, 
    10.52, 9.32, 9.87, 8.77, 10.19, 10.72, 9.42, 10.06, 10.66, 
    10.2, 10.32, 10.57, 10.16, 11.5, 9.28, 10.73, 11.06, 11.07, 
    10.22, 9.5, 9.15, 9.95, 8.87, 9.56, 9.44, 10.42, 9.91, 9.56, 
    9.97, 8.62, 8.91, 11.12, 9.35, 9.97, 8.71, 10.19, 10.18, 
    9.81, 9.46, 10.09, 10.05, 9.46, 11.22, 9.54, 9.33, 9.19, 
    10.18, 9.47, 9, 9.98, 10.03, 10.63, 10.53, 10.47, 9.39, 9.5, 
    9.16, 9.48, 8.7, 9.45, 11.01, 10.06), fam = structure(c(48L, 
    496L, 761L, 628L, 1666L, 818L, 853L, 511L, 1123L, 548L, 1494L, 
    1031L, 134L, 283L, 1066L, 224L, 1189L, 863L, 82L, 815L, 1075L, 
    1578L, 103L, 440L, 205L, 332L, 343L, 292L, 583L, 905L, 690L, 
    718L, 135L, 1593L, 1075L, 1253L, 345L, 466L, 626L, 710L, 
    58L, 415L, 756L, 1133L, 385L, 668L, 1424L, 1506L, 933L, 536L, 
    33L, 336L, 1281L, 1306L, 1672L, 564L, 458L, 1651L, 994L, 
    1032L, 231L, 32L, 911L, 1417L, 1046L, 1572L, 734L, 1241L, 
    1090L, 1007L, 974L, 910L, 985L, 446L, 760L, 1584L, 761L, 
    717L, 687L, 1168L, 78L, 59L, 893L, 1264L, 1226L, 494L, 1663L, 
    987L, 1009L, 75L, 808L, 70L, 384L, 394L, 467L, 788L, 1470L, 
    1389L, 1446L, 1083L, 1524L, 1363L, 407L, 1011L, 121L, 265L, 
    1609L, 1193L, 1577L, 529L, 1034L, 1025L, 1213L, 361L, 483L, 
    846L, 830L, 487L, 875L, 42L, 941L, 1293L, 348L, 665L, 1574L, 
    901L, 1634L, 1342L, 501L, 757L, 159L, 996L, 534L, 411L, 411L, 
    1116L, 1370L, 1229L, 739L, 1408L, 407L, 872L, 814L, 676L, 
    1625L, 714L, 180L, 562L, 1060L, 1564L, 1358L, 383L, 652L, 
    215L, 1252L, 1449L, 1000L, 1526L, 1217L, 778L, 621L, 396L, 
    23L, 1665L, 1611L, 1666L, 1284L, 169L, 52L, 1310L, 818L, 
    801L, 605L, 587L, 1164L, 226L, 873L, 190L, 857L, 1098L, 1516L, 
    1369L, 250L, 1644L, 225L, 657L, 738L, 983L, 1000L, 1481L, 
    984L, 376L, 489L, 809L, 1129L, 316L, 1469L, 428L, 316L, 82L, 
    856L, 1518L, 207L, 983L, 217L, 719L, 1097L, 136L, 748L, 167L, 
    1652L, 1085L, 232L, 930L, 918L, 1162L, 922L, 966L, 1223L, 
    586L, 72L, 615L, 775L, 452L, 1113L, 1209L, 193L, 750L, 315L, 
    246L, 472L, 200L, 1112L, 955L, 948L, 997L, 1638L, 777L, 966L, 
    566L, 1662L, 1052L, 1477L, 1303L, 677L, 1588L, 1142L, 320L, 
    998L, 1572L, 1276L, 1121L, 1141L, 1402L, 251L, 1269L, 870L, 
    35L, 1325L, 1537L, 591L, 203L, 1621L, 1243L, 1164L, 582L, 
    1399L, 1642L, 755L, 553L, 60L, 980L, 892L, 956L, 534L, 634L, 
    793L, 113L, 635L, 1350L, 188L, 626L, 1308L, 1234L, 917L, 
    123L, 505L, 398L, 1249L, 243L, 387L, 865L, 984L, 1146L, 1460L, 
    1576L, 543L, 1063L, 1508L, 717L, 736L, 763L, 27L, 813L, 1089L, 
    1617L, 1271L, 1507L, 76L, 1638L, 1084L, 1067L, 893L, 821L, 
    451L, 439L, 452L, 786L, 361L, 1377L, 1568L, 984L, 59L, 1597L, 
    1485L, 1056L, 324L, 641L, 339L, 785L, 834L, 1527L, 1623L, 
    551L, 1092L, 380L, 730L, 1343L, 1318L, 1241L, 79L, 284L, 
    735L, 1126L, 194L, 856L, 577L, 49L, 258L, 877L, 234L, 4L, 
    1174L, 1230L, 946L, 522L, 753L, 260L, 1574L, 1418L, 1309L, 
    1296L, 319L, 836L, 783L, 1284L, 778L, 79L, 623L, 972L, 1642L, 
    1298L, 110L, 1442L, 459L, 506L, 1032L, 1431L, 1143L, 395L, 
    1415L, 145L, 1483L, 691L, 742L, 321L, 788L, 99L, 1507L, 683L, 
    1500L, 1509L, 533L, 79L, 343L, 424L, 1260L, 206L, 1083L, 
    1321L), levels = c("1", "9", "11", "17", "32", "38", "40", 
    "43", "47", "57", "79", "83", "86", "91", "101", "111", "116", 
    "125", "138", "146", "156", "173", "195", "197", "239", "278", 
    "291", "306", "365", "383", "398", "408", "421", "458", "478", 
    "491", "510", "541", "545", "551", "559", "563", "591", "594", 
    "598", "600", "605", "635", "652", "659", "695", "712", "750", 
    "758", "771", "772", "775", "787", "790", "795", "798", "804", 
    "808", "809", "819", "829", "839", "850", "852", "856", "859", 
    "867", "877", "888", "890", "903", "917", "920", "922", "929", 
    "939", "953", "959", "961", "973", "980", "984", "987", "995", 
    "997", "1013", "1016", "1021", "1028", "1038", "1043", "1048", 
    "1057", "1060", "1067", "1072", "1077", "1082", "1084", "1087", 
    "1095", "1096", "1104", "1111", "1133", "1134", "1139", "1141", 
    "1147", "1153", "1155", "1182", "1197", "1200", "1207", "1209", 
    "1217", "1230", "1246", "1258", "1262", "1270", "1281", "1287", 
    "1288", "1289", "1291", "1297", "1298", "1300", "1308", "1311", 
    "1315", "1321", "1330", "1332", "1337", "1339", "1358", "1364", 
    "1374", "1375", "1379", "1380", "1392", "1396", "1398", "1403", 
    "1406", "1407", "1418", "1425", "1427", "1436", "1440", "1442", 
    "1454", "1473", "1479", "1481", "1492", "1494", "1499", "1502", 
    "1522", "1525", "1532", "1541", "1545", "1549", "1550", "1551", 
    "1559", "1561", "1572", "1582", "1584", "1585", "1603", "1605", 
    "1607", "1619", "1620", "1638", "1646", "1656", "1660", "1663", 
    "1666", "1669", "1677", "1683", "1696", "1698", "1700", "1716", 
    "1719", "1725", "1726", "1734", "1737", "1754", "1762", "1765", 
    "1771", "1786", "1803", "1810", "1812", "1815", "1816", "1817", 
    "1819", "1829", "1832", "1837", "1848", "1853", "1875", "1885", 
    "1896", "1906", "1913", "1948", "1950", "1957", "1965", "1996", 
    "2012", "2019", "2035", "2045", "2057", "2100", "2108", "2154", 
    "2155", "2177", "2206", "2222", "2253", "2265", "2271", "2337", 
    "2356", "2368", "2414", "2420", "2447", "2486", "2491", "2493", 
    "2495", "2507", "2525", "2529", "2531", "2548", "2550", "2558", 
    "2562", "2565", "2569", "2574", "2579", "2588", "2589", "2593", 
    "2594", "2597", "2605", "2620", "2629", "2634", "2643", "2648", 
    "2658", "2664", "2676", "2686", "2710", "2718", "2724", "2739", 
    "2744", "2747", "2755", "2758", "2769", "2779", "2783", "2801", 
    "2803", "2806", "2812", "2814", "2829", "2858", "2881", "2893", 
    "2898", "2900", "2903", "2913", "2921", "2929", "2937", "2948", 
    "2957", "2993", "3012", "3015", "3029", "3064", "3066", "3072", 
    "3127", "3133", "3137", "3162", "3185", "3189", "3191", "3198", 
    "3200", "3202", "3207", "3210", "3213", "3216", "3219", "3224", 
    "3225", "3227", "3229", "3236", "3239", "3241", "3243", "3247", 
    "3253", "3256", "3257", "3263", "3265", "3269", "3272", "3274", 
    "3277", "3279", "3283", "3285", "3288", "3290", "3299", "3300", 
    "3304", "3307", "3310", "3312", "3318", "3320", "3322", "3326", 
    "3330", "3334", "3337", "3341", "3345", "3352", "3356", "3359", 
    "3363", "3367", "3369", "3374", "3376", "3379", "3393", "3397", 
    "3399", "3402", "3404", "3408", "3415", "3420", "3424", "3426", 
    "3431", "3434", "3436", "3440", "3442", "3443", "3445", "3447", 
    "3450", "3454", "3456", "3459", "3461", "3462", "3464", "3466", 
    "3470", "3473", "3474", "3476", "3479", "3483", "3488", "3491", 
    "3494", "3495", "3498", "3502", "3507", "3509", "3519", "3521", 
    "3524", "3527", "3535", "3539", "3541", "3543", "3545", "3546", 
    "3551", "3552", "3554", "3562", "3564", "3567", "3568", "3569", 
    "3571", "3572", "3574", "3576", "3578", "3582", "3586", "3590", 
    "3592", "3594", "3597", "3601", "3602", "3607", "3608", "3609", 
    "3614", "3615", "3617", "3618", "3620", "3623", "3624", "3625", 
    "3626", "3627", "3629", "3634", "3636", "3638", "3641", "3643", 
    "3644", "3646", "3652", "3656", "3664", "3666", "3670", "3674", 
    "3675", "3678", "3681", "3684", "3685", "3688", "3690", "3692", 
    "3693", "3695", "3696", "3697", "3698", "3701", "3705", "3708", 
    "3710", "3714", "3715", "3716", "3718", "3719", "3721", "3726", 
    "3729", "3731", "3732", "3734", "3738", "3739", "3740", "3742", 
    "3743", "3744", "3747", "3748", "3749", "3750", "3751", "3753", 
    "3755", "3758", "3759", "3760", "3762", "3763", "3764", "3766", 
    "3768", "3769", "3770", "3772", "3774", "3775", "3777", "3781", 
    "3785", "3787", "3790", "3791", "3816", "3823", "3839", "3847", 
    "3856", "3864", "3880", "3885", "3890", "3892", "3902", "3910", 
    "3914", "3929", "3936", "3938", "3940", "3943", "3950", "3955", 
    "3965", "3970", "3979", "4014", "4023", "4041", "4061", "4080", 
    "4095", "4135", "4142", "4152", "4157", "4159", "4162", "4167", 
    "4171", "4174", "4180", "4191", "4201", "4209", "4213", "4214", 
    "4217", "4226", "4239", "4260", "4262", "4269", "4283", "4318", 
    "4319", "4340", "4374", "4398", "4405", "4428", "4435", "4437", 
    "4438", "4446", "4450", "4468", "4474", "4486", "4494", "4497", 
    "4519", "4543", "4550", "4552", "4555", "4559", "4613", "4623", 
    "4638", "4640", "4654", "4668", "4671", "4689", "4711", "4723", 
    "4775", "4779", "4796", "4800", "4813", "4819", "4823", "4832", 
    "4833", "4841", "4907", "4910", "4912", "4915", "4936", "4960", 
    "4962", "4971", "4987", "4993", "4995", "5006", "5016", "5034", 
    "5079", "5123", "5128", "5137", "5142", "5165", "5188", "5213", 
    "5241", "5263", "5266", "5275", "5298", "5299", "5333", "5344", 
    "5346", "5348", "5358", "5364", "5367", "5389", "5394", "5398", 
    "5403", "5405", "5409", "5412", "5416", "5422", "5426", "5432", 
    "5442", "5460", "5471", "5473", "5474", "5476", "5478", "5484", 
    "5497", "5502", "5505", "5507", "5509", "5511", "5512", "5514", 
    "5516", "5519", "5523", "5525", "5530", "5534", "5541", "5545", 
    "5547", "5550", "5555", "5556", "5558", "5560", "5565", "5570", 
    "5575", "5578", "5583", "5595", "5597", "5605", "5616", "5618", 
    "5623", "5626", "5631", "5633", "5636", "5639", "5640", "5644", 
    "5661", "5668", "5677", "5681", "5682", "5684", "5691", "5696", 
    "5698", "5705", "5709", "5711", "5714", "5715", "5716", "5721", 
    "5723", "5732", "5735", "5739", "5740", "5742", "5746", "5749", 
    "5750", "5752", "5754", "5755", "5767", "5771", "5777", "5779", 
    "5782", "5788", "5790", "5793", "5794", "5795", "5798", "5800", 
    "5803", "5806", "5808", "5809", "5815", "5817", "5819", "5821", 
    "5826", "5829", "5832", "5835", "5837", "5839", "5847", "5849", 
    "5852", "5853", "5858", "5859", "5863", "5868", "5870", "5872", 
    "5874", "5875", "5878", "5882", "5883", "5884", "5885", "5886", 
    "5889", "5890", "5892", "5894", "5896", "5900", "5901", "5902", 
    "5905", "5908", "5911", "5912", "5915", "5922", "5923", "5924", 
    "5926", "5928", "5930", "5932", "5933", "5934", "5940", "5942", 
    "5944", "5947", "5949", "5950", "5953", "5956", "5961", "5968", 
    "5969", "5972", "5975", "5983", "5984", "5987", "5989", "5990", 
    "5991", "5995", "5996", "5998", "6002", "6003", "6005", "6011", 
    "6012", "6014", "6017", "6018", "6020", "6021", "6022", "6025", 
    "6027", "6034", "6036", "6041", "6043", "6045", "6046", "6049", 
    "6052", "6056", "6072", "6078", "6082", "6115", "6122", "6140", 
    "6142", "6143", "6151", "6165", "6172", "6187", "6211", "6233", 
    "6265", "6269", "6276", "6297", "6321", "6337", "6355", "6368", 
    "6370", "6389", "6403", "6406", "6418", "6429", "6437", "6444", 
    "6449", "6461", "6482", "6484", "6488", "6506", "6511", "6519", 
    "6548", "6554", "6581", "6593", "6598", "6622", "6630", "6690", 
    "6695", "6702", "6706", "6718", "6725", "6736", "6740", "6744", 
    "6767", "6792", "6805", "6807", "6820", "6823", "6844", "6851", 
    "6867", "6871", "6879", "6901", "6903", "6911", "6930", "6945", 
    "6963", "6970", "6989", "6994", "6996", "7011", "7022", "7032", 
    "7033", "7038", "7042", "7044", "7046", "7053", "7065", "7070", 
    "7076", "7078", "7083", "7088", "7095", "7097", "7101", "7103", 
    "7106", "7122", "7126", "7134", "7136", "7138", "7140", "7148", 
    "7149", "7152", "7155", "7159", "7162", "7164", "7166", "7168", 
    "7174", "7176", "7179", "7181", "7189", "7192", "7195", "7199", 
    "7205", "7207", "7210", "7211", "7214", "7217", "7220", "7226", 
    "7228", "7240", "7248", "7251", "7254", "7258", "7261", "7262", 
    "7266", "7270", "7271", "7274", "7278", "7280", "7281", "7283", 
    "7285", "7287", "7289", "7294", "7296", "7297", "7298", "7303", 
    "7306", "7308", "7309", "7312", "7313", "7324", "7326", "7328", 
    "7333", "7337", "7338", "7340", "7342", "7344", "7346", "7352", 
    "7359", "7361", "7362", "7364", "7366", "7373", "7375", "7377", 
    "7380", "7381", "7384", "7386", "7388", "7396", "7399", "7401", 
    "7402", "7405", "7408", "7415", "7418", "7424", "7425", "7426", 
    "7428", "7429", "7431", "7433", "7438", "7440", "7441", "7442", 
    "7443", "7445", "7447", "7451", "7452", "7455", "7457", "7458", 
    "7459", "7464", "7465", "7468", "7469", "7471", "7473", "7475", 
    "7476", "7477", "7479", "7480", "7481", "7483", "7485", "7486", 
    "7489", "7492", "7494", "7497", "7499", "7502", "7504", "7507", 
    "7508", "7511", "7514", "7515", "7516", "7517", "7518", "7523", 
    "7526", "7528", "7529", "7531", "7538", "7539", "7540", "7541", 
    "7543", "7547", "7551", "7554", "7556", "7557", "7559", "7560", 
    "7561", "7564", "7566", "7567", "7569", "7570", "7571", "7573", 
    "7574", "7575", "7576", "7577", "7579", "7582", "7583", "7585", 
    "7586", "7587", "7588", "7590", "7604", "7615", "7617", "7637", 
    "7653", "7669", "7685", "7690", "7693", "7702", "7706", "7725", 
    "7740", "7748", "7757", "7760", "7762", "7806", "7810", "7818", 
    "7830", "7831", "7841", "7850", "7863", "7880", "7903", "7942", 
    "7946", "7950", "7965", "7970", "8001", "8003", "8010", "8014", 
    "8016", "8020", "8021", "8024", "8033", "8034", "8040", "8056", 
    "8092", "8094", "8130", "8131", "8132", "8133", "8139", "8153", 
    "8191", "8193", "8194", "8202", "8206", "8214", "8216", "8223", 
    "8239", "8242", "8243", "8244", "8248", "8256", "8264", "8274", 
    "8279", "8283", "8288", "8293", "8324", "8328", "8330", "8343", 
    "8359", "8364", "8366", "8376", "8396", "8399", "8413", "8426", 
    "8435", "8445", "8446", "8472", "8477", "8483", "8499", "8504", 
    "8521", "8522", "8527", "8543", "8560", "8580", "8597", "8612", 
    "8636", "8655", "8668", "8678", "8692", "8701", "8713", "8718", 
    "8720", "8730", "8735", "8749", "8758", "8762", "8763", "8799", 
    "8808", "8817", "8838", "8842", "8849", "8856", "8857", "8862", 
    "8870", "8874", "8879", "8888", "8892", "8909", "8940", "8955", 
    "8962", "8972", "9001", "9013", "9023", "9025", "9038", "9057", 
    "9063", "9066", "9079", "9085", "9091", "9097", "9104", "9120", 
    "9143", "9181", "9191", "9201", "9213", "9216", "9239", "9251", 
    "9271", "9294", "9310", "9323", "9329", "9348", "9385", "9393", 
    "9398", "9403", "9416", "9426", "9440", "9444", "9446", "9474", 
    "9494", "9524", "9586", "9612", "9616", "9628", "9634", "9642", 
    "9645", "9656", "9679", "9687", "9689", "9690", "9696", "9716", 
    "9764", "9789", "9793", "9805", "9822", "9833", "9839", "9864", 
    "9885", "9892", "9929", "9931", "9949", "9958", "9967", "9979", 
    "9986", "10008", "10039", "10066", "10100", "10136", "10146", 
    "10193", "10209", "10210", "10223", "10227", "10245", "10252", 
    "10266", "10273", "10310", "10343", "10354", "10359", "10361", 
    "10369", "10380", "10382", "10386", "10397", "10399", "10403", 
    "10412", "10416", "10423", "10429", "10443", "10444", "10447", 
    "10450", "10459", "10463", "10466", "10488", "10495", "10496", 
    "10508", "10557", "10577", "10586", "10594", "10603", "10620", 
    "10625", "10651", "10656", "10664", "10666", "10688", "10705", 
    "10711", "10719", "10730", "10737", "10746", "10747", "10749", 
    "10750", "10755", "10762", "10785", "10789", "10797", "10799", 
    "10800", "10828", "10830", "10848", "10849", "10850", "10871", 
    "10872", "10879", "10889", "10891", "10892", "10893", "10894", 
    "10906", "10916", "10942", "10948", "10961", "10967", "10985", 
    "10991", "11003", "11034", "11038", "11045", "11047", "11060", 
    "11065", "11074", "11077", "11086", "11090", "11104", "11123", 
    "11135", "11152", "11153", "11155", "11160", "11187", "11190", 
    "11196", "11208", "11234", "11241", "11261", "11272", "11277", 
    "11297", "11308", "11317", "11323", "11326", "11330", "11333", 
    "11336", "11338", "11341", "11345", "11348", "11350", "11353", 
    "11359", "11363", "11371", "11377", "11378", "11383", "11386", 
    "11390", "11392", "11394", "11396", "11398", "11404", "11406", 
    "11408", "11411", "11415", "11417", "11420", "11422", "11423", 
    "11427", "11429", "11433", "11438", "11440", "11443", "11449", 
    "11453", "11457", "11459", "11461", "11465", "11467", "11468", 
    "11474", "11476", "11479", "11486", "11488", "11490", "11492", 
    "11495", "11498", "11500", "11503", "11505", "11507", "11513", 
    "11515", "11517", "11519", "11522", "11526", "11529", "11534", 
    "11538", "11540", "11542", "11545", "11549", "11551", "11553", 
    "11554", "11556", "11559", "11561", "11566", "11571", "11573", 
    "11574", "11578", "11584", "11585", "11587", "11590", "11593", 
    "11594", "11603", "11610", "11611", "11617", "11618", "11619", 
    "11620", "11624", "11626", "11628", "11632", "11633", "11637", 
    "11639", "11641", "11642", "11644", "11648", "11650", "11654", 
    "11661", "11663", "11664", "11668", "11673", "11675", "11677", 
    "11679", "11682", "11685", "11690", "11691", "11693", "11694", 
    "11695", "11698", "11699", "11700", "11702", "11703", "11704", 
    "11707", "11708", "11713", "11714", "11717", "11719", "11721", 
    "11724", "11725", "11728", "11730", "11733", "11735", "11737", 
    "11740", "11741", "11744", "11745", "11748", "11749", "11751", 
    "11753", "11755", "11760", "11764", "11766", "11767", "11768", 
    "11770", "11772", "11774", "11775", "11784", "11785", "11788", 
    "11791", "11793", "11795", "11796", "11797", "11798", "11802", 
    "11804", "11806", "11809", "11813", "11818", "11820", "11821", 
    "11824", "11825", "11826", "11831", "11832", "11835", "11836", 
    "11839", "11840", "11841", "11843", "11845", "11846", "11848", 
    "11849", "11850", "11851", "11852", "11854", "11855", "11856", 
    "11860", "11864", "11868", "11872", "11873", "11874"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -400L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think you have identified your own issue -- you do not have a proper grouping variable. It looks like each ID should have between 1 and 5 observations. If you look at the output of your attempt you are just giving each row a distinct ID.

Comment: The data do not appear to be in any meaningful order to identify the groups so doing something like `seq(nrow(mwe)) %/% 6` would not help especially if you having missing observations. Grouping by `fam` and `zyg` does not uniquely identify your units either.

Comment: **edit: the simulation seems correct,  the data is nested in waves, and in zyg and in families**. @LMc each row is an observation, the variable fam has the nesting I mention. I only care about the first MZ of the family or the first DZ of the family.